# Convert Array to JSON with ID's as Index (MongoDB / Express)

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, data-structures

I have an `user schema` in my mongodb database which saves users. In mongoose I write:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},
  password: String,
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  articles: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "article"
  }]
})
```

I've saved a few users to that Collection. When I query my api for users, I get back an *array* of User objects. Like so:

```
[
  {
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "_id": "5b36292760afa11b9a216945",
  "email": "user@mail.de",
  "__v": 0
  },
  {
  "first_name": "Lisa",
  "_id": "5bafkjahf123123123123125",
  "email": "lisa@mail.de",
  "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Is this normal behaviour? And is this coming from the Mongo side of things or the express side? I heard that something like this is more common:

```
{
 "5b36292760afa11b9a216945":{
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "email": "user@mail.de",
  "__v": 0
  },
 "5bafkjahf123123123123125":
  {
  "first_name": "Lisa",
  "email": "lisa@mail.de",
  "__v": 0
  }
}
```

- ? How could I convert my array into this kind of a JSON? Is there some functionality maybe within mongo that does that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get an object like that back from mongo, but it's not hard to convert it with `Array.reduce()`.

```js
let returnedValue = [{"first_name": "Bob","_id": "5b36292760afa11b9a216945","email": "user@mail.de","__v": 0},{"first_name": "Lisa","_id": "5bafkjahf123123123123125","email": "lisa@mail.de","__v": 0}]

let result = returnedValue.reduce((a, c) => (a[c._id] = c, a), {})
console.log(result)
```

This leaves the `_id` in the original object, but if you needed to inside the reduce function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation as well

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id",
        "v": {
          "first_name": "$first_name",
          "email": "$email"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "5b36292760afa11b9a216945": {
      "email": "user@mail.de",
      "first_name": "Bob"
    },
    "5bafkjahf123123123123125": {
      "email": "lisa@mail.de",
      "first_name": "Lisa"
    }
  }
]
```